# Let's burninate [magazine]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

I found today that we have a tag [magazine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/magazine) (only 16 closed questions). Most of the questions there revolve around creating (online) magazines, or making a layout look like a magazine.

"Magazine" is not useful to classify questions. It is a meta-tag, because it conveys no meaning by itself - what does it mean for a programming question to be about magazines?

I suggest we burninate it.

Comment: The tag is strongly associated with mobile GUI design frameworks, Apple tags up front.  Your profile suggests that's not something you ever do.  Don't kill what you don't recognize, SO has a very long tail.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm not active in the Apple tags, so maybe I am indeed missing something here. But it seems a meta-tag to me.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm going to have to disagree here with [tag:magazine] being associated with UI frameworks. The tag appears to be grouping together questions _about_ magazines: some about the iOS/Android apps, some about copying/implementing those, and others about web-based magazines. If it's supposed to be mobile UI design, I think [tag:magazine] started off as a bit too general for it. **Maybe a tag wiki can get it back on track?**

Comment: Well, your beef is not with me, it is with 43 users that have struggled with their magazine-style GUI layout and hope to find somebody that's familiar with the markup that required.   And beneficial to the many hundreds of SO users that don't give a hoot about layout problems so can quickly tell that visiting the question is pointless.  I don't see a point in taking that option away from them, it is entirely harmless.

Comment: @HansPassant In that case, maybe the tag should have a different name. Something like magazine-layout . I'd prefer that over a tag wiki, although a tag wiki is a good idea either way.

Comment: How about magazine-layout?

Comment: Down to 29 questions now. I would argue against @HansPassant that this is like the *kittens* case in the [burnination guideline](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191).

Comment: There are now 15 closed questions and only 1 open

Comment: @VadimKotov ... and that one is textbook Too Broad. Voted to close. (Although a tag for a magazine-style layout, as was suggested by Robert Harvey, _might_ be useful),

Comment: Suggestion: rename this request into the general burnination style like: *Let's burn-inate this [magazine]